# React scoped stylesheets

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, create-react-app

I have an application that I am building. I have built both a back and front end in static html. These have both been built from paid templates online but both depend on different versions of bootstrap 3 & 4.

I have started building a React app off the react-create-app starter but have hit a dead end in getting my html to style correctly.

Is there a way to scope css to components so that it is only added into the dom when the component is rendered? I have created the concept of a FRONTEND and BACKEND component these components wrap pages. In these components I have tried modifying the HEAD tag to add/remove style sheets which does work but leaves broken html for a second while the page renders.

Any ideas? I've been stuck on this one most of the day.

Comment: There was 'scoped' for a period of time. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_style_scoped.asp but this is slowly going away - if you are facing these issues think about why you are using 2 different frontend libs and why they need to both be included on the same pages.

Comment: Convert your styles to CSS modules or styled-components.

Comment: @lumio not sure how css modules are meant to help OP in using two different versions of bootstrap.

Answer (score -1):

I highly recommend against what you are doing. But if you really must, you can put each component in a separate `iframe` to separate the css and use one redux store to feed data into both iframes and keep them in sync.

Comment: If you are going to down vote my answer, it'd be good to know your reasoning.